# Delphi 7 & ICS sending DELETE requests

Tags: delphi, rest, delphi-7

How can I send a DELETE request with delphi 7 and the ICS component so that I can access a REST api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use the [synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php) library.  Its very easy to use and extend.  I have modified it for use against a REST api without any major problems.

Answer (score 1):

All I could find...

http://wiki.overbyte.be/wiki/index.php/THttpCli.OnBeforeHeaderSend